# Python: Can't continually catch keyboardinterrupt in Windows?

Tags: python, windows, terminal

In Python, I wrote the following code to see if I could get my program to not terminate upon Control+C like all those fancy terminal apps such as Vim or Dwarf Fortress.

```
def getinput():
    x = input('enter something: ')
while True:
    try:
            getinput()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass
```

Unfortunately, in the Windows console, this script terminates after a few seconds. If I run it in IDLE, it works as expected. Python version is 3.2.1, 3.2 acted the same. Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: If I hold down, Control+C, that is.

Comment: Works for me on Windows console, Python 3.2. What are you expecting to happen and what actually happens? What error is raised?

Comment: I edited the answer to be clearer. If I hold down Control+C, in the console it terminates without an error, whereas IDLE performs as expected and keeps displaying 'enter something: '.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to not terminate on `Control-C` you need to set a signal handler.
From the Python doc [here](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html)

> Python installs a small number of
>   signal handlers by default: SIGPIPE is
>   ignored (so write errors on pipes and
>   sockets can be reported as ordinary
>   Python exceptions) and SIGINT is
>   translated into a KeyboardInterrupt
>   exception. All of these can be
>   overridden.

So you would need to install a signal handler to catch the `SIGINT` signal and do what you want on that.

The behavior with IDLE is probably that they have a handler installed that blocks the application exit.

Comment: The interactive interpreter from Windows' command line works without issues as well, so that all makes sense. Thanks for the help!